# Motivation of countable additivity in probability theory

Tags: probability-theory

I looked at the lecture note saying that when $\Omega$, a sample space, is uncountably infinite, then we would have problem without countable additivity axiom. Can you please give me an example?

Also, I looked at the extension theorem (Thr 3.1 of Billingsley, P. Probability and Measure). It states that for a probability measure, $P$, a field $F$ of subsets of $\Omega$, then there exists a probability measure $Q$ on $\sigma({F})$, generated $\sigma$-fields by $F$ such that $Q(A) = P(A), \forall A\in F$. Suppose $\Omega$ is an uncoutable infinite sets, then how one can have probability measure, $P$ in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Royden's book produces a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ using the axiom of choice.  When the underlying set is uncountable, it is common for non-measurable sets to exist.